# RenderAction inside a View when incoming URL ends with colon throws error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Looking at my ASP MVC's ELMAH log files, I can see this error coming through quite often:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
   at System.Web.InternalSecurityPermissions.PathDiscovery(String path)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
   at ...\Views\Layout\_Header.cshtml:line 10
```

Here is the offending code:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("HeaderCart", "ShoppingCart", new{area = ""});}
```

We render a few partials from the site's layout before hitting any RenderActions -- this is the first one that's called, and throws the error.

When a particular URL (which is matched using a custom MVC Route) is called that ends in ":" then the error is thrown.

It's coming quite deep from inside MVC - any ideas how to work around this?